# How can I configure a dumb parallel printer for OpenERP Point of Sales?

Tags: printing, plaintext, openerp-7, receipt, parallel-port

[Originally posted to the OpenERP forum last month to no avail, with minor changes here to clarify.]

A group I work with has inherited a free receipt printer with a cash drawer. It uses a parallel interface, and there appears to be no know driver for it. (It's a Star SP-200.) A simple Python script sending "Hello World!^G" to /dev/lp0" successfully prints "Hello World!" and opens the cash drawer (as do "lp" and "lpr" with files containing a Ctrl-G).

However, using OpenERP's Point of Sale module, receipts printed to either the Generic Raw Queue or the Generic Text-Only printer result in what appears to be PDF being sent to the printer.

This is with Ubuntu 13.10, and the latest OpenERP from the repository (7.0-20140326) as well as the most recent PoS.

Is there either some clever OpenERP setting we've missed, or some clever CUPS setting / PPD file that will result in plain text being sent, followed by the ^G to open the drawer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the pos proxy at https://github.com/Fedrojesa/ProxyPoS. There are the installation instructions. I have not tried it myself though but i have the same problem.I think it just works with printers usig the ESC/POS Language.Look for the ESC/POS python module.

Answer (score 0):

As @hydroslll suggested, you can use the ProxyPoS from https://github.com/Fedrojesa/ProxyPoS. Currently is not prepared for print on parallel printers, but if as you said a simple python script can make the job, we can also adapt the ProxyPoS as is python too.

Let me know if you need any more specific help.